# Batch concatenation string with special characters

Tags: string, batch-file, dos, concatenation

## Context

I check several servers with nmap and I send the result by email.

I concatenate a variable with new result for each server and each ports with this code (I removed loops):

```
SET text=
SET text=!text!+"<h1>server %%i:</h1>
SET text=!text!+"Port %%a : %%b<br/>"
SET text=!text!+"<br/>"
```

And I send one email with `text` variable.

Email rendering:

```
server 2:

+Port 8443 : https-alt
+
+
server 3:

+Port 2103 : zephyr-clt
+Port 2105 : eklogin
+Port 2107 : msmq-mgmt
+Port 49155 : unknown
+
+
```

I try whithout `+` but it doesn't work:

```
SET text=
SET text=!text! "<h1>server %%i:</h1>
SET text=!text! "Port %%a : %%b<br/>"
SET text=!text! "<br/>"
```

I try unsuccessfully several alternatives.

## Question

How to concatenate my `text` variable without ugly `+`?

## Answer which works

```
SET "text="
SET "text=!text! ^<h1^>server %%i^</h1^>^<br/^>"
SET "text=!text! Port %%a %%b^<br/^>"
SET "text=!text! ^<br/^>"
%blat% -server %server% -port %port% -f %from% -to %to% -html -s "Opened ports" -body "!text!"
```

Comment: @vulkanino Yes but I tried [this](http://www.dostips.com/?t=Snippets.StringConcatenation) and it doesn't work in my case.

Comment: which DOS are you using? isn't it CMD under Windows?

Comment: Batch file on Windows Server 2008.

Comment: the `+` is not needed, but I think you have a `"` that shouldn't be there

Comment: What's the reason to use multiple sets? I would just write:  `set text=^<h1^>server %%i:^</h1^> Port %%a : %%b ^<br/^>` (`^` is escape char so you could pass < and >)

Comment: @GG it's difficult to tell what's not working for you, as I checked the output before I posted and volcanino did as well. Check that you consistently use " (quote) or not use it at all. My version does not require quotes. Put echo !text! after you set it (and pause) so you can see what's going on

Comment: Actually I sent `!text!` by email and it needed quotes as `"!text!"`. I use your tip with `^` to send HTML and it works great! thanks all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
set "str1=Hello"
set "str2=World"

set "str3=%str1%%str2%"
set "str4=%str1% %str2%"
```

Output:

```
HelloWorld
Hello World
```

It doesnt work because you have special character in your strings (quotes, <, >, \, etc.).
You have to use the quote " and the remove the quotes with the following code:

```
:NOQUOTES
       SET _string=###%_string%###
       SET _string=%_string:"###=%
       SET _string=%_string:###"=%
       SET _string=%_string:###=%
```

Comment: With this level of complexity, why not VBScript under [Windows Script Host](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Script_Host)? Later, if you need a decent GUI, you can reuse your VBScript in an [HTML Application](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_Application).

Answer (score 4):

The premise behind your question is flawed. Both sets of code build a text variable with special characters preserved. One has `+`, one doesn't. The `+` has nothing to do with concatenation in batch programming. It is simply a character like any other.

The special characters `<` and `>` are preserved because you have enclosed them in quotes. *(Actually, the server line is missing the closing quote. But CMD.EXE happens to be forgiving. You probably should add the closing quote though for clarity.)*

You don't have to worry about existing special charactes inside `!text!` because delayed expansion protects the special characters. If you were using `%text%` instead then you *would* have to worry about special characters within the value.

If you are concerned about whether the text is what you expect, you should look at the value of the text variable, not the output in your mail message. Add debug code like

```
set text
```

or

```
echo text=[!text!]
```

to your code to see the value after it is built. (I added the square brackets just so you can see trailing spaces.)

The fact that the version with the `+` works with your email while the one without does not has nothing to do with the building of the text string. It must be something that is happening after you build text, something to do with the handling of the mail message itself.

I don't understand why the quotes in your text are not appearing in your mail message. Again there must be something going on after you build your text.

vulkanino suggested a method for removing quotes from text, but his solution is overly complex. In fact he had a perfectly good method at the top of his answer and didn't realize it - there is no reason to have them there in the first place.

```
SET "text="
SET "text=!text! <h1>server %%i:</h1>"
SET "text=!text! Port %%a : %%b<br/>"
SET "text=!text! <br/>"
```

Note the opening quote *before* the variable name. This form will preserve special characters without including quotes in the value.

An alternative method to preserve special characters without quotes in the value is to escape the special characters.

```
SET text=
SET text=!text! ^<h1>server %%i:^</h1^>
SET text=!text! Port %%a : %%b^<br/^>
SET text=!text! ^<br/^>
```

I think the quoted solution is much nicer.

Comment: +1 for detailed explanation by far exceeding OP original question

Comment: +1 as the answer explains the background of special characters, variables and output